# Why does my MongoDB database URI listed on Heroku have a replica set option, while the one listed on MongoLab does not?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, replication, mlab, replicaset

I setup a MongoDB database on MongoLab through Heroku. I selected the free, single-node, sandbox plan, not any of the replica set clusters.

The page for my database on MongoLab shows the following URI to connect to the database:

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds012345.mongolab.com:12345/heroku_app12345678
```

Heroku lists the same `MONGOLAB_URI` under Config Variables in the Settings section, but appends a replica set option to it: `?replicaSet=rs-ds012345`.

I understand that the replica set option [specifies the name of the replica set, if the mongod is a member of a replica set.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#replica-set-option)

Since it appears that I did not select a replica set cluster plan when setting up the database on MongoLab, why does Heroku's `MONGOLAB_URI` configuration variable seem to indicate that the database is a member of a replica set?

Which URI should I use in my app built with Node.js and Express?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bug. Please write us at support@mongolab.com and we'd be happy to help.